# Viewing a web page inside another in a cordva ios app

Tags: javascript, html, ios, cordova

We are building a Cordova iOS App, with a HTML page showing another online page. It is working fine in Safari, but doesn't work when we build the app.

Here is the code we tried. It works on Safari (on Mac and iPhone 7), but doesn't work on iOS as a Cordova App

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>In My Home</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
    <object type="text/html" data="https://mylink.com/../index.html">
    </object>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="../cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/landscape.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Some possible causes we thought of:

1. The app needs a special permission (?)
2. The HTML code needs some parameters (?)
3. Something else (??)

Thanks!

Comment: use `cordova-plugin-inappbrowser` plugin

Answer (score 0):

You can use an iframe:

```
<iframe src="https://mylink.com/../index.html">
</iframe>
```

but you can have some troubles if it's not the same domain (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy)

A good alternative is to use zoid (https://github.com/krakenjs/zoid).